# Encountering InsecurePlatformWarning while installing South for Python on Terminal

Tags: python, installation, django-south

New to python, I am trying to install south on terminal, yet I kept receiving this error:

```
error: could not create '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/south': Permission denied
```

followed by:

```
 Command "/usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/0h/l9sjp7_50kj0581vz9xtwm5w0000gp/T/pip-build-iJUmlt/south/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/0h/l9sjp7_50kj0581vz9xtwm5w0000gp/T/pip-Z8bOI8-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/0h/l9sjp7_50kj0581vz9xtwm5w0000gp/T/pip-build-iJUmlt/south
```

Is this a security issue? As I have been surfing the net for answers, I have tried to install 'some hidden security features' with this:

```
pip install requests[security]
```

Or, is this because of the version of python that I'm using?

After many tries, I still ended up with the same error. Can somebody maybe answer this hassle that I am dealing with? Any help will be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

Your urllib3 is out of date.  Update.

Answer (score 0):

## Short answer:

The `InsecurePlatformWarning` is due to your Python & `urllib3` version.

If you don't care about security, just disable the warning:

```
export PYTHONWARNINGS="ignore:A true SSLContext object is not available"
```

Your `Permission denied` error looks like a file permissions issue.  The user you are running `pip` or `setuptools` as does not have write access to: `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/south`.  It looks like you are on a Mac, so you should either:

1. Use `--user` flag for pip, (**recommended**)
   i.e.: `pip install --user foo-package`
   This will install packages to: `/Users/your-username-here/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/`
   **Note:** [This is your "per user site-packages directory](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0370/)
2. Use `sudo` to install as root: `sudo pip install foo-package`
3. Change ownership for `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages` to your user (**not recommended**):
   `sudo chown -R your-username-here:wheel /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages`

## Long answer:

This warning is given on platforms with older versions of Python where `urllib3` & `requests` can't control or do not support some of the SSL options required to ensure a secure connection to the server.

### Affected Versions

You will probably run into this with: `Python <= 2.7.9`, `urllib3 >= 1.11`

### urllib3 Documentation

The [`urllib3` Documentation](http://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning) explains the error message like this:

> New in version 1.11.
>
> Certain Python platforms (specifically, versions of Python earlier than 2.7.9) have restrictions in their ssl module that limit the configuration that urllib3 can apply. In particular, this can cause HTTPS requests that would succeed on more featureful platforms to fail, and can cause certain security features to be unavailable.
>
> If you encounter this warning, it is strongly recommended you upgrade to a newer Python version, or that you use pyOpenSSL as described in the OpenSSL / PyOpenSSL section.
>
> For info about disabling warnings, see Disabling Warnings.

Historically, urllib3 had never actually been secure.  The [first heading in the urllib3 docs states this](http://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#security-verified-https-with-ssl-tls):

> Very important fact: By default, urllib3 does not verify HTTPS requests.
>
> The historic reason for this is that we rely on httplib for some of the HTTP protocol implementation, and httplib does not verify requests out of the box. This is not a good reason, but here we are.
>
> Luckily, it’s not too hard to enable verified HTTPS requests and there are a few ways to do it.

### Workarounds

#### Disabling Warnings

If you just need to silence the warning, there are a couple ways.  The easiest is to just set the `PYTHONWARNINGS` environment variable before running your python code like this:

```
export PYTHONWARNINGS="ignore:A true SSLContext object is not available"
```

This should work in Python 2.7+, and you can alternatively use the `-W` flag for the Python interpreter.

You can also [Disable Warnings](http://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#disabling-warnings) in the code, or with the `logging` module:

```
# To disable all urllib3 warnings
import urllib3
urllib3.disable_warnings()

# To capture warnings to your own log with the logging module
logging.captureWarnings(True)
```

#### Installing SNI Support on Older Python

The [urllib3 Documentation shows how to install SNI support](http://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#installing-urllib3-with-sni-support-and-certificates):

> If you need to use SNI on Python 2.6 or Python 2.7.0-2.7.8, you have to install PyOpenSSL, ndghttpsclient, and pyasn1 separately. Further, to use certifi you have to install it separately. If you know that you want these dependencies when you install urllib3, you can now do:

```
pip install urllib3[secure]
```

> Note If you do this on linux, e.g., Ubuntu 14.04, you will need extra system dependencies for PyOpenSSL. Specifically, PyOpenSSL requires cryptography which will require you to install:

```
build-essential
python-dev
libffi-dev
libssl-dev
```

> The package names may vary depending on the distribution of linux you are using.

### More Detailed Technical Information

[GitHub user dstufft](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/2681#issuecomment-92541888) explains in more detail why old versions of Python cannot ensure a secure connection:

> Unless you have Python 2.7.9+ or Python 3.2+ urllib3 (via requests) can't control some of the SSL options it needs to in order to ensure a secure connection to the server. In particular:
>
> - On Python 2.6, it can't set the ciphers at all so it relies on the platform defaults.
> - It can't disable TLS Compression.
> - It can't disable SSLv3 without having to explicitly pin to TLSv1.0.
> - It can't (along with an OpenSSL that is new enough to support it) tell OpenSSL to prefer a shorter, but still valid certificate chain which makes it hard to remove the weak 1024 bit keys from the trust root without breaking a lot of otherwise valid TLS connections.
> - It doesn't support SNI, which forces a pip compatible repository to use burn a whole IP address just to use TLS, while not strictly related to security it can be the difference between someone using verified TLS and not verified TLS.